# Django: How to print to logs the value of a database field?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am using the done() method of a SessionWizardView to update two counters in my Database. I want to print the value of both counter fields into my log files.

How to I access and log the value of `survey_wizard_count` and `total_max_counter`?

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    survey_counter = Counter.objects.get_or_create(survey_wizard_type = 'survey_wizard_one')[0]

    survey_counter.survey_wizard_count = F('survey_wizard_count') + 1 
    survey_counter.total_max_counter = F('total_max_counter') + 1 
    survey_counter.save()


    logger.debug('This is your survey_wizard_count = %s', ????????????????)
    logger.debug('This is your total_max_counter = %s', ????????????????)

    for form in form_list:
        form.save()

    return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to be using F objects here. Those are useful when doing an `update` query directly, but here you have the object already. Just reference the values:

```
survey_counter.survey_wizard_count += 1 
survey_counter.total_max_counter += 1 
survey_counter.save()
```

Now you can log the values directly:

```
logger.debug('This is your survey_wizard_count = %s', survey_counter.survey_wizard_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
logger.debug("This is your survey_wizard_count is: " + survey_counter.survey_wizard_count)
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I have tried a few solutions like this. Unfortunately your suggestion gives `[10/Jul/2015 19:03:00] DEBUG [survey:553] (+: This is your survey_wizard_count is: , (DEFAULT: ), 1)` The value should simply be 6